# SharePoint 2013 - Result Type - Combine types of documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, result-source

While I love how my Search Center has the Result types and the different types of documents, I am the minority since I have the knowledge of what type of document I'm often looking for when I'm searching.

Right now, I have the result type listing Excel, OneNote, PDF, PowerPoint, Word, all separately. Most staff don't know what type of document - just that it is a document versus a Website or a Site. Is there a way to change the result type to offer the option of "Documents", "Pages, "Sites" rather than each of these document types separately?

Comment: You mean to merge xslx, word, ppt, pdf to "Document" in your refinement? If yes, you can do that in the display template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats possible by creating a new Result type which would be the combination of the two document types and if you want to customize user experience and provide more information in the search result you could use display templates.

On this page there is a section that shows steps to create a custom result type and configuration:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135239.aspx